# Image href is larger than the image itself. Not sure how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, github, atom-editor, portfolio

I am working on my portfolio for school and we have to use github to make it. I can't seem to figure out how to reduce the href clickable link size to match the size of the actual image. For some reason, it's a lot bigger than it should be, so I would end up clicking on the link even though my mouse would be way off from the image.

Here is my html code for the images:

```
<div class="icons">
  <a href="assets/Flood.mp4" onclick="lightbox_open();"><img src="assets/Floodbw.png" alt="flood" style="float: right; width: 20%; margin-right: -0.5%; margin-left: -0.25%; margin-bottom: -0.5%;">
  <a href="assets/project_2_documentation_edit_2.mp4" onclick="lightbox_open();"><img src="assets/Dependencybw.png" alt="Dependency" style="float: right; width: 20%; margin-right: -0.5%; margin-left: -0.25%; margin-bottom: -0.5%;">
  <a href="assets/project1.mp4" onclick="lightbox_open();"><img src="assets/Disposalbw.png" alt="Disposal" style="float: right; width: 20%; margin-right: -0.5%; margin-left: -0.25%; margin-bottom: -0.5%;"></a>
  <p style="clear: both;">
</div>
<div class="icons2">
  <a href="assets/Seamstress.mp4" onclick="lightbox_open();"><img src="assets/Buttonsbw.png" alt="buttons" style="float: right; width: 30.1%; margin-right: -0.72%; margin-left: -0.5%; margin-top: -1.8%; margin-bottom: -0.8%;">
  <a href="assets/Narrative.mp4" onclick="lightbox_open();"><img src="assets/Bitterbw.png" alt="Bitter;">
</div>
```

And here is my css code:

```
.icons{
  margin-top: -0.5%;
}

.icons2 img{
  float: right; width: 30.1%; margin-right: -0.72%; margin-left: -0.5%; margin-top: -1.8%; margin-bottom: -0.8%;
}
```

And here is the link to my portfolio (still a work in progress on other pages):
https://elizabethnnguyen.github.io/digitalworks.html

The images I am referring to are the red and blue images of the flower girl and buttons under the video works section.

Comment: You don't close off four of your five `<a>` tags with `</a>`. Adding those in should fix the problem. If not, you might want to run your HTML through a markup validator.

Comment: Its HTML structure issue please post full code of your project via codepen or fiddle

Comment: thank you both for your tips! Turns out, it was just an <a> tag problem, which @ObsidianAge mentioned!